# In how many ways can nine women and six men be seated at a circular table so that no two men are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A committee of 15 -- 9 women and 6 men -- is to be seated at a circular table (with 15 seats). In how many ways can the seats be assigned so that no two men are seated next to each other?

I am thinking like if we had 5 men 5 women we have 5!5! ways. Similarly we can say lets first put 6 men. Then to divide them put 6 women. Then still we have 3 women. Lets also but remaning 3 women by placing between existing people.
6! . p(9,6) . 12. 13. 14

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @caribax I have written a solution and will undelete it after you have included in the question your own thoughts on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I think it is more difficult to place men first, because afterwards, women must be distributed and there will in some cases be several women between men and they will have to be chosen. So as a courtesy, place the women first by swapping them, choose from 9 possible locations, six places for the men. Only one man per place. You have to swap them. Attention the table is round, if it is rotated some placements are identical.

Comment: @almagest I already put my answer when I edited my question

Answer (score 3):

Select any woman. There are then 8! ways of placing the other women clockwise from her. There are then 9 potential gaps between adjacent women. At most one man can sit in any of these potential gaps. We select 6 of them in ${9\choose6}$ ways. There are then 6! ways of placing the men in those gaps. So the men can be seated in $9!/3!$ ways. So far we have got $$8!\ 9!/3!=6720\cdot9!=2438553600\quad(*)$$ At this point you have to decide whether moving everyone a seat to the left gives you a different arrangement, or whether you only care about the order. If it matters who sits in a particular seat, then we need to multiply the number so far by 15 to get $$\frac{5}{2}\cdot8!\cdot9!=36578304000$$ If you only care about the order, then $(*)$ is the answer.